# Showing the max key:value Dictionaries inside a list

Tags: python

How to show the max `key: value` dictionaries inside a list
the code shown below can only show the values.

```
ages = [{'Matt': 30, 'Katie': 29}, {'Nik': 31, 'Jack': 43,}, {'Alison': 32, 'Kevin': 38}]

max_age = int()

for dict in ages:
    if max(dict.values()) > max_age:
        max_age = max(dict.values())

print(max_age)
```

Is there any way to show the max key also with the value?

Comment: The maximum key, or the key associated with the maximum value? These are different things.

Comment: @j1-lee the output only is 42

Comment: I need to add the key with It, not only the value

Comment: @9769953, the key associated with the maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three tools that make short work of this problem.

- The [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function with a *key* argument selects the largest input according to the criteria in the key-function.
- The [`itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function extracts the second value in a tuple.
- A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) takes care of looping and accumulating the results.

This leads to simple and elegant code:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [max(m.items(), key=itemgetter(1)) for m in ages]    
[('Matt', 30), ('Jack', 43), ('Kevin', 38)]
```